# How to add new rows to SQL results?

Tags: sql

I am trying to automate one of the report but I am having difficulties due to adjustments which takes place manually. I need to add new rows to my results approximately 40-50 new rows.

Sample of my query:

```
Select


CASE WHEN... end as F_Code
,CASE ... end as F_Position
,Round ... balance_eur

 --Merging columns--              
,F_Position||';;'||F_Code||';'||balance_eur||';;;' "1X209;JE;10;100;4;2018;UU"

from ODS.SAP_GL_BALANCES SGLB;
```

My results;

```
F_POSITION  F_CODE   BALANCE_EUR      1X209;JE;10;100;4;2018;UU
931112510   13150    -892704.53       931112510;;13150;-896382,31;;;
```

How can I add multiple rows into my results such as;

```
F_POSITION  F_CODE   BALANCE_EUR      1X209;JE;10;100;4;2018;UU
931112510   13150    -892704.53       931112510;;13150;-896382,31;;;
95XXXXXXX   15000     12.12           95XXXXXXX;;15000;12,12;;;
93XXXXXXX   14000     187.18          93XXXXXXX;;14000;187,18;;;
93XXXXXXX   14000    -35.56           93XXXXXXX;;14000;-35,56;;;
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is not clear and requires too much effort to be understood. It does not seem you put a real effort in solving your problem, if yes, descrribe better what you want to achieve and what you already tried. Your questions looks like "I do not want to solve this, please do it for me", this kind of questions find an hard way in StackOverflow.

Comment: Why not add the records to the table? or add the records after calling the query? I didn't quite get the desired outcome. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Hi LaBracca, thank you for the explanation. I am able to get he results that I want but due to the manual adjustments which are done in excel I am not able to get precise results. So I would like to add those adjustments to my result as a row 40-50 rows in total but I dont know how can I add into my result. I tried select from dual but it adds only 1 row :/

due to I have limited rights I can not use insert option thats why I am kind of stuck

Comment: Please be precise. There is a lot of missing contexts in your question. We cannot help you if you won't clarify the problem and give more details.

Comment: Make it easy (and possible) to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tried to simplify it, I hope it is more clear now.. I am new to the space, apologies if I am expressing my question wrongly.

Comment: Sample table data and the expected result is a great start when asking questions. Also a query attempt that actually executes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION ALL` to add rows manually to your result:

```
SELECT ... -- your query
UNION ALL
select '95XXXXXXX', 15000, 12.12, '95XXXXXXX;;15000;12,12;;;' from dual
UNION ALL
select '93XXXXXXX', 14000, 187.18, '93XXXXXXX;;14000;187,18;;;' from dual
UNION ALL
select '93XXXXXXX', 14000, -35.56, '93XXXXXXX;;14000;-35,56;;;' from dual;
```